# firebase click button to trigger build and deploy

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am currently using firebase to build a static site.

I am doing things rather manually, everytime I make some changes I would need to do a build then a deploy, which looks something like this:

`npx eleventy` followed be `firebase deploy`

I am looking for a programmatic approach for this and have done one with a bash script attached to cronjob. All these are happening locally. I am just wondering if there is a better way to approach this, am possibly looking for the following

1. Having a button on a separate site to trigger both the build and hosting commands on click.
2. Hosting my cronjob onto firebase/GCP (I understand that I should be looking in this direction? - https://cloud.google.com/scheduler)

I am looking for a clearer direction to head to especially for point 1. (Feel free to weigh in on point 2 as well). Great thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a CI/CD tool. Like Travis or Circle CI. 
You can configure it so that as soon as some change is committed it triggers a build and then deploy it to firebase hosting.

Comment: I understand that Travis CI triggers a deploy on a push from git. But building a static site I'm basically just building new static assets that I don't have to push to git. Also, Travis CI cronjobs are only limited to daily (whereas i may need hourly etc). Any solutions for this?